# Is there a way to subtract column 'A' present in Stream1 from column 'B' present in Stream2?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading 2 streams(stream1 & stream2) from Kafka in spark structured streaming (pyspark). I have to calculate the difference between the offsets of stream1 and stream2.

I am trying something like this:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
root
|--timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- value: string (nullable = true)
|-- offset: double (nullable = true)
|-- string_val: string (nullable = true)
|-- ping: double (nullable = true)
|-- date: string (nullable = true)
|-- time: string (nullable = true)
|-- offset_v1: double (nullable = true)
|-- date_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- date_format: timestamp (nullable = true)

<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
|-- Mean: double (nullable = true)
|-- pingTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- Std_Deviation: double (nullable = true)
|-- devTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- offset_v2: double (nullable = true)
|-- upperBound: double (nullable = true)
|-- lowerBound: double (nullable = true)

stream2 = stream2.withColumn('difference',stream2.offset_v2-stream1.offset_v1)
```

It throws an error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Resolved attribute(s)
>   offset_v1#95 missing from
>   upperBound#182,Std_Deviation#149,lowerBound#189,Mean#133,pingTime#129-T30000ms,devTime#144-T30000ms,offset_v2#155 in operator !Project [Mean#133, pingTime#129-T30000ms,
>   Std_Deviation#149, devTime#144-T30000ms, offset_v2#155,
>   upperBound#182, lowerBound#189, (offset_v2#155 - offset_v1#95) AS
>   difference#233]

Comment: you would need to do a join to get a `Dataframe` that has all the relevant columns needed for u to calculate difference

Comment: I don't have any column using which I can perform the join operation. Without joining, is there any way?

Comment: How do you match rows from both sides and calculate difference for offsets? That just needs join.

Answer (score 0):

Like Venki said, you need to join first to compare relevant rows together. Do you have any column to do that ? A **date** ir an **id** would do the trick. Let's assume you have one named **join_col** in **both dataframes**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

stream_final = stream1.join(stream2, 'join_col', 'inner')

# Now compute difference by adding a new column 'offset_diff':

stream_final = stream_final.withColumn('offset_diff', stream_final.offset_v1 - stream_final.offset_v2)
```

If you can't find a proper join, this is a problem for cases where you compare columns with different lengths which I believe is what you're dealing with.

Comment: I don't have any column using/upon which I can perform the join operation. Without joining is there any way?